# how to insert a line break in tex4ht in \Hcode?

Tags: fonts, line-breaking, tex4ht

I got the problem that I need to produce Javascript Code with a certain structure. I need a line break or new line at a certain point, but no html-tags or similar in my code. Below there's a simplified example. (Obviously, I don't really know which packages regarding font handling I need. Any hints on that are appreciated.) As a second point, I'd like to have the letter ä appearing in the html code, i.e. var b1ä = ... in the example below, and all my attempts have been without success so far.

Best

Christian

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage,german,twoside]{book}%
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{30}
\Preamble{xhtml}
% Configure for mathjax
\Configure{VERSION}{}
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{\HCode{<!DOCTYPE html>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html>\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />\Hnewline
}}


\begin{document} 
\EndPreamble
\shorthandoff{"}

\author{Ich}
\title{Dynamische Volkswirtschaftslehre }
Text \newline
\HCode{
<div id="box" class="jxgbox" style="width: 770px; height:
500px;"></div> <script >// <![CDATA[ }\Hnewline
\HCode{
var b1 = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('box',
{boundingbox: [-1, 11, 11, -1], axis:true, keepaspectratio:true,
showCopyright:false});
 // ]] } \HCode{>  </script>}


\end{document}
```

The resulting code is:

```
<body>
<!--l. 28--><p class="noindent" >Text <br
class="newline" /> <div id="box" class="jxgbox" style="width: 770px; height: 500px;"></div> <script >// <![CDATA[  &#x02D9; var b1 = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('box', {boundingbox: [-1, 11, 11, -1], axis:true, keepaspectratio:true, showCopyright:false}); // ]]  > </script>
</p>
</body>
```

Instead of the ˙ I need just a new line, i.e.

```
<div id="box" class="jxgbox" style="width: 770px; height: 500px;"></div> <script >// <![CDATA[ 
var b1 = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('box', {boundingbox: [-1, 11, 11, -1], axis:true, keepaspectratio:true, showCopyright:false}); // ]]  > </script>
```

Comment: You could use `\Hnewline` inside `\HCode{}`.

Comment: Or you can use `\hfill\break` outside `\HCode{}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\Hnewline`, which works only inside `\HCode` command for newline insertion.

I would modify your code to be more portable, it won't compile to PDF as it is, furthermore, it causes compilation error even with `tex4ht`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage,german,twoside]{book}%
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newenvironment{mygraph}{}{}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{30}

\begin{document} 
\shorthandoff{"}

\author{Ich}
\title{Dynamische Volkswirtschaftslehre }
Text \newline
\begin{mygraph}

\end{mygraph}

\end{document}
```

I've removed all `tex4ht` commands and introduced `mygraph` environment, which will be used to insert the script environment.

`tex4ht` configuration will be placed in custom `.cfg` file, `hello.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
% Configure for mathjax
\Configure{VERSION}{}
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{\HCode{<!DOCTYPE html>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html>\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />\Hnewline
}}
\ScriptCommand{\JavaScript}{}{}
\ConfigureEnv{mygraph}{%
\HCode{%
<div id="box" class="jxgbox" style="width: 770px; height:
500px;"></div> <script >// <![CDATA[ \Hnewline
var bä1 = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('box',\Hnewline
{boundingbox: [-1, 11, 11, -1], axis:true, keepaspectratio:true,\Hnewline
showCopyright:false});\Hnewline
 // ]]></script>}}
{}{}{}

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

`myscript` environment is configured using `\ConfigureEnv{myscript}`, as you can see, only one `\HCode` command has to be used, newlines are inserted using `\Hnewline`.

Regarding accents inside `\HCode`, it is possible with unicode TeX engine, which means LuaTeX, as XeTeX is not supported by tex4ht at the moment.

Compile the document using:

```
 make4ht -ulc hello.cfg filename.tex
```

and this is the resulting HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> <title></title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<!-- charset=utf-8,html,xhtml --> 
<meta name="src" content="sample.tex" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sample.css" /> 
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" /> 
</head><body 
>
<!--l. 18--><p class="noindent" >Text <br 
class="newline" /><div id="box" class="jxgbox" style="width: 770px; height: 500px;"></div> <script >// <![CDATA[  
var bä1 = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('box', 
{boundingbox: [-1, 11, 11, -1], axis:true, keepaspectratio:true, 
showCopyright:false}); 
// ]]></script>
</p>   

</body> 
</html>
```