# tex4ht: pretty formatting of newline inside html source

Tags: line-breaking, tex4ht

When I compile a `latex` document with `tex4ht` (under Tex Live 2016 / Windows 10) using

```
htlatex "my_doc.tex" "xhtml,charset=utf-8,fn-in" " -cunihtf -utf8"
```

latex `\newline` or `\\` command is rendered in HTML source as

```
... <br 
class="newline" /> ...
```

instead of a more pleasant (no line break inside the tag and a line break after the tag)

```
... <br class="newline" />
...
```

Is this a general issue? (I guess so because I've seen [this same formatting around](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/318526/28685), if it's not I will post a MWE)

Is it possible to fix this, maybe with a custom configuration?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explicit linebreaks are configured using `\Configure{linebreak}`. The default configuration is:

```
 \Configure{newline}{\HCode{<br\Hnewline class="newline" />}}
```

as you can guess, `\Hnewline` requests line break in the source code, so it is quite easy to modify it to suit your needs. Complete `.cfg` file

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{newline}{\HCode{<br class="newline" />\Hnewline}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```